keep foots on the ground
**Hello everyone
I made a simple character of an animal and i want to keep foots on the ground, for foot i only inserted upper leg bone and lower leg bone. There are no ankle or foot bones.
So my question is there a way to keep the foots on the ground without having ankle, foot bones? because the legs here in this character are simple.
Thank you
**

Add a foot bone even if there is no foot, make sure it's not child of the leg (it can be child of the hips or, better, child of a root bone).
Uncheck its "Deform" option in the bone properties panel.
Select the foot bone, shift select the shin bone, press Ctrl Shift C and choose IK bone constraint. Set its chain lenght to 2.
In edit mode, make sure that thigh and shin bones are not exactly vertical: move the knee joint a bit in front of the character, where the bend will have to go.


I can't thank you enough, I have one more question do you recommend to use automatic weight for this type of character because weight paint is so confusing or should i use assign points in vertex groups?

Automatic weight is a good starting point, then you can paint or assign in edit mode if something is unsatisfying.

Additionally you can add a Floor constraint to keep the feet from moving below a certain point in space. Makes animating a bit easier.

It's a great solution too thank you @Jakemoyo
